# MySQL to PostrgreSQL encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, utf-8

I guess i's over 9000 question on this and I've read a lot of artciles about this and issues like this, but I still can't get clear data in Postgre table.

I have a MySQL database, which is set to utf-8 by default, charset of website is set to utf either. But if I look into DB I see `Ð”ÐΜÐºÐ¾Ñ€`.
However, the output on a webpage is fine.

I know now, that this is cp1252, which is nowhere been set (as far as I can see).

If I transfer data to Postrgre, output is all like `Ð”ÐΜÐºÐ¾Ñ€` opposite to MySQL with the same data and settings.

Things I've tried:

1. Dump sql file, recreated the database(ensure it's utf), executed sql - no result;
2. `mysqldump dbname -u root -p --default-character-set=latin1 > dump.sql` - no result;
3. I've tried to convert the dump file: `iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 dump.sql -> new.sql` - no result;

I wouldn've posted this question, but I've wasted really a lot of time on this already and I do need help

Comment: So the loading / resore is Ok, but the characters appear garbled once you retrieve them ? Try setting `SET client_encoding = cp1252;` (or latin9) in your client/front-end

Comment: Hey, @joop, thanks for your comment. But I can see this solution only as a workaroud. I have no doubt it will clearify the output (I used this once), but it'll still be a garbage it a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to convert everything I need, glad the database is not really big. Did it by this function:

```
mb_convert_encoding($model->text, 'cp1252', 'utf8')
```